# Reusing adopted storage

Tags: adoptable-storage

I have sdcard formated as adopted storage. I have also root and made a copy of encryption key which is in `/data/misc/vold` dir. I'm using it to access files on sdcard on PC with Linux. I'm planning to format /data partition and set up everything from beginning. Question is if I place same sdcard, with same content (formated previously as adopted storage) in phone and key file in `/data/misc/vold` from TWRP can I be able to access files on fresh system?

Comment: Since key is getting erased when you perform factory reset you may be able to do so but maybe when you put your key in that system it will screw up everything related to system. Isn't it easier to backup data to pc and then format the card too and restore backup just to avoid something going badly.

Comment: I can but this take time. That's why I'm asking if it's possible to do it.

Comment: You have TWRP so why not just try and answer the question by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected. After wiping data partition and rebooting to system I made encryption of data partition as I always do. Then again reboot to recovery. I copied encryption key for sdcard (with the same content, I didn't format sdcard) to `/data/misc/vold` and make sure that file belongs to root.

After rebooting to system again I didn't have any notification about formating sdcard. One thing I had to do: move data to sdcard. And after this step, I can see all my content on sdcard, which was mounted as adopted storage.